MT7621: How to modify DTS file for adding a new SPI device
I have a board that has MT7621 SOC with an LE9622 through SPI interface.
I should mention that the only SPI interface of MT7621 is handling the SPI Flash, and I am going to use the same interface for LE9622 but with different chipselect.
For adding the child node under the SPI interface of MT7621 Device Tree file, I am trying to define a child node and define the LE9622 there.
My problem is that I do not find any information about LE9622 on the Device Tree bindings subdirectory of kernel to understand how to define the child node.
openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt7621/linux-5.15.142/Documentation/devicetree/bindings
Does any one know where I can find information about a LE9622 driver for Linux kernel?
Can anybody help me to add child node in device tree for LE9622?
My Device Tree file is as following:
 / {
     compatible = "meisam,7621a-evb", "mediatek,mt7621-soc";
     model = "MAM-7621A board";
 
     keys {
         compatible = "gpio-keys";
         reset {
             label = "reset";
             gpios = <&gpio 18 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
             linux,code = <KEY_RESTART>;
        };
     };
 };
 
 &spi0 {
     status = "okay";
 
     flash@0 {
         compatible = "jedec,spi-nor";
         reg = <0>;
         spi-max-frequency = <44000000>;
         broken-flash-reset;
 
         partitions {
             compatible = "fixed-partitions";
             #address-cells = <1>;
             #size-cells = <1>;
 
             partition@0 {
                 label = "u-boot";
                 reg = <0x0 0x30000>;
                 read-only;
             };
 
             partition@30000 {
                 label = "u-boot-env";
                 reg = <0x30000 0x10000>;
                 read-only;
             };
 
             factory: partition@40000 {
                 label = "factory";
                 reg = <0x40000 0x10000>;
                 read-only;
 
                 nvmem-layout {
                     compatible = "fixed-layout";
                     #address-cells = <1>;
                     #size-cells = <1>;
 
                     eeprom_factory_8000: eeprom@8000 {
                         reg = <0x8000 0x200>;
                     };
                 };
             };
 
             partition@50000 {
                 compatible = "denx,uimage";
                 label = "firmware";
                 reg = <0x50000 0x1fb0000>;
             };
         };
     };
 };

I could not define the codec "LE9622" with SPI interface in the device tree file of the MT7621.
Can anyone give me support to resolve this problem?

ADDENDUM
This is the block diagram of my circuit:


I tried to define the LE9622 with below code in the dts file:
    proslic_spi: proslic_spi@0 {
        compatible = "silabs,si3210";
        reg = <0>;
        spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
        spi-cpha = <1>;
        spi-cpol = <1>;
        channel_count = <1>;
        debug_level = <4>;       /* 1 = TRC, 2 = DBG, 4 = ERR */
        reset_gpio = <&pio 7 0>;
        ig,enable-spi = <1>;     /* 1: Enable, 0: Disable */
    };

But faced with below error during compile.
ERROR (phandle_references): /palmbus@1e000000/spi@b00/proslic_spi@0: Reference to non-existent node or label "pio"


One problem is that there does not seem to be a kernel driver for the LE9622. From the compatible = "silabs,si3210"; property, I see you are attempting to set it up as an "spidev" device to allow it to be driven from userspace. If this is on chip select 1, you need to change proslic_spi@0 to proslic_spi@1 and change reg = <0>; to reg = <1>;. Also, according to the datasheet, the minimum SPI clock period is 122ns, so set spi-max-frequency = <8000000>;. You can probably get rid of spi-cpha, spi-cpol, channel_count, debug_level, reset_gpio, and ig,enable-spi.
